# Is this potential sugar daddy trying to scam me?

Tags: scams, check, sugar-daddy

A potential sugar daddy requested that I send him my email & name, so he can send me a check. He said he wants to use the mobile deposit to send me the money. Once the mobile deposit has been completed, my allowance will be available in my account. He said he has tried that many times before.

He will be taking photos (back and front) of the check, send it to me through email, and I am going to deposit it myself. I have to print it out or send it to another device and take the pictures.

Is it a scam??? I feel like it is but I don't know, as I am new to being a sugar baby and, thus, I am not sure how this whole thing of sugar daddy and sugar baby works.

Comment: Have you searched this site? There are many examples of similar scams.

Comment: If he really wants to legitimately send you money, there are already a dozen ways to do it with only a phone number.

Comment: they're **always** scams.

Answer (score 9):

Inevitably this will turn out to be a scam.

First, most sugar baby relationships will involve providing sexual favors of some sort to the "daddy", at least the exchange of erotic pictures. Folks willing to pay money for a text only, non-erotic online relationship are very, very rare. Scammers are very, very common. Second, the excuses about being unable to to mobile deposit and asking you to make a mobile deposit using the images they send don't make any sense, a sure sign of a scam, and that's why you feel unsure about it.

At this point it's impossible to tell what the scam will eventually be. One angle might be to get you to make the deposit, then send you a threat like "Ha! You deposited a stolen check in  your account. Send me money or I'll tell the bank and the police." More common would be a simple follow up request to send back a portion of the money "as a sign of trust", using bitcoin, gift cards, or western union". A few weeks later your bank will figure out that the image you deposited was bogus or stolen, and roll back the deposit. You will be on the hook to pay the bank back for any of the money that you spent, and you'll have no way of calling back the gift card or bitcoin that you sent.

It's a scam. Block them.